# How to include an independent source in two-port theory

Tags: passive-networks

how does one include an independet current or voltage source as a two-port.

With ABCD matricies it's easy to cascade multiple networks together.
So let's assume we have a two port connected to a source and a two port again. What is the transmission matrix of that whole system? In the book "EMC analysis methods and computational models" by Tesche I found an equvivalent circut. I will attach a picture.

The problem is if i add the vector with [vs;is] I can't multiply another two-port to cascade.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The transmission matrix of the cascade of two two-port networks is NOT the product of the matrices of the two two-port network.

Why?

Because the second two-port network acts as a load to the first.

The four elements of the first matrix were calculated, by definition, with the second (right) port open.

If you put a decoupler circuit in the middle, for example a unity gain buffer, then you can multiply the two matrices.

The matrix of a decoupler circuit is the identity matrix with 1's on the diagonal and 0's elsewhere.